# Change Paypal donation button on hover

Tags: html, css, paypal

I made a Paypal donation button at the PayPal page with a custom image. Is there any chance that the image changes the color or different image on hover?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="RX3MLKWPQBLSN" />
  <input type="image" src="https://domain.sk/paypal2.png" border="0" name="submit" title="PayPal - The 
safer, easier way to pay online!" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_SK/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can use filter css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp or you can use js to replace input src on hover.

Comment: @Unbranded Manchester , would you be so kind and help me with the code please?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS method will only let you manipulate the image that you already have and is the method that will use the least resource.

```
.paypal_button:hover {
  filter: contrast(50%);
}
```

jQuery is a lot heavier, but using jQuery you can swap out the image using mouseover and mouseout. (I've used a placeholder image to show the example here). This will give you the most freedom in replacing the image source to whatever you want when someone hovers.

```js
  $( ".paypal_button" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/qvga/000000");
  });
  
    $( ".paypal_button" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/qvga");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="RX3MLKWPQBLSN" />
  <input type="image" class="paypal_button" src="https://dummyimage.com/qvga" border="0" name="submit" title="PayPal - The 
safer, easier way to pay online!" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_SK/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

Comment: that jQuery working perfectly on code pen, but how do I put this code as a widget in wordpress ? There is only "your own HTML". Where do I put the javascript?

Comment: Add the jquery between <script> and </script>